# Why this is not working in c++ but work in python

Tags: python, c++

Here is my both code i want to convert my python code to c++

Python and c++ code below

```py
if n%2 and k>n//2:
    print(n%2,n//2)
    arr[n//2]=0
rem=k%(3*n)

for i in range(k-rem,k):
    t=i%n
    arr[t]^=arr[-1-t]

#print(arr)
print(*arr)
```

c++ code

```cpp
if((n%2!=0) && (k>n/2))
    a[n/2]=0;

rem=k%(3*n);

for(i=k-rem;i<k;i++)
{
    l=i%n;
    a[l]^=a[-1-l];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What values do `k` and `n` have, and what output are you getting, and what output do you expect to get?

Comment: C++ doesn't allow indexing an array using a negative value. (`array[<negative value>]`) . Since `l=(i%n)` is always positive, `-1-l` is always negative. So you probably are getting segmentation fault or memory corruption or something of that  sort with this program


To be more precise, C++ technically doesn't care about the sign of the index, but it is undefined behavior. array[value] roughly translates to `*(&array[0] + value)`

Comment: I know that but please provide me the correct code or what I have to do in place of this

Comment: The expected output is not obviously garbage value but this is giving @Kevin

Answer (score 5):

In this Python code

```
arr[t]^=arr[-1-t]
```

one of the indices will be negative and interpreted as "from the end of the array" C++ doesn't have that. As such:

```
a[l]^=a[-1-l];
```

will trigger undefined behavior (UB). This is not a correct C++ program.

Comment: I know that but please provide me the correct code or what I have to do in place of this

Comment: I'm purposefully not giving a ready-to-use piece of code. Otherwise this site would become a big "do my homework" site. But if you're willing to learn, we'll guide you.

Answer (score -1):

C++ doesn't allow any negative index for the array.

From your python statement `arr[t]^=arr[-1-t]`, it seems you are trying to access elements from last.

So in C++, if you want to have the same functionality then you can use `a[t]^=a[(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])) -1 -t]`.

Comment: Sizeof is incorrect there. Sizeof units are bytes. What is needed there is the size of the array in elements. Also, sizeof pointer doesn't give you the size of the whole array.

Comment: Edited the code. IF I go through the python code given in the question, it seems that the user is trying to loop through array/list from last to front. So in C++ we can iterate backward decrementing the value of the size of the array.

Comment: Thanks bro your last approach helped me bro I am making a silly mistake and not using l there thank you bro

Comment: Glad, it helped you.